# Android Ksoap2 web service

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, ksoap

I want to make an application using SOAP web service, in which I have a web service that communicates with three android devices. Two of my android devices will send some data to the web service, and the web service will send this data to my last android device. I want to know if it's possible to transfer data from that two android device to the web service using KSOAP2 library, or if exists other implementing ideas in which I can transfer data from that two devices to my last one.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the above implementation .You  can define  a message format that can be understand by a webservice to transfer a data to the last one.